# Solving second-order nonlinear differential equation $y''y+5y^6(y')^4=2(y')^2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve a second-order nonlinear DE in the form
$$
y''y+5y^6(y')^4=2(y')^2
$$
I've already tried a couple of substitutions, including $y'=p(y)$ and $\frac{y'}{y}=p(y)$ and none of them seem to have worked. Could you please provide any clues on how to approach this?

Comment: you can get rid of one term by setting $y=1/u\implies 5u'^{\,4}=u^{11}u''$ but still not very appealing.

Comment: @zwim : That gives $5u'/u^{11}=u''/u'^3$ for a first integration, $u^{-10}+C=u'^{-2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $y'(x) = p(y)$, so $y'' = p'(y) p(y)$, and (after dividing by $p(y)$) the equation becomes
$$ p'(y) y + 5 y^6 p(y)^3 = 2 p(y) $$
which is a Bernoulli equation.  Then substitute $p(y) = \pm u(y)^{-1/2}$ to get a linear equation in $u$:

$$ u'(y) = 10 y^5 - 4 u'(y)/y $$
Solve this to get
$$ u(y) = y^6 + c/y^4 $$
so that
$$ y'(x) = p(y) = \pm \frac{y^2}{\sqrt{y^{10}+c}}$$
and finally
$$ \pm \int \frac{\sqrt{y^{10}+c}}{y^2}\; dy = x + k $$
The integral probably can't be done in "closed form".

Comment: isn't the ' in $p'(y)$ supposed to be a differentiation against $y$ variable and not $x$ for it to be a Bernoulli ode for $p$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote it as $p'(y)$.